# iTextSharp Render HTML img as a hyperlink

Tags: html, image, itext, anchor, href

We are using iTextSharp to render HTML as  PDF. We have a requirement to render an image as a hyperlink. We have HMTL code such as

```
  <a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'
       <img src='D:\Folder\btnconfirm.png'/>Confirm</a>
```

We get an error saying nested tags are not allowed. Cannot recognize 'a'. Is there a solution for this?

Regards,
Shilpa

Comment: Also: are you using `HTMLWorker` (bad idea) or are you using iTextSharp's XML Worker (good idea). You don't say anything about the way you render HTML to PDF. Maybe you're using `HTMLWorker` and maybe you don't know that `HTMLWorker` has been abandoned in favor of XML Worker.

Comment: Also, your sample is missing closing quotes for the `href` and `src` attributes, is that in your live code, too?

Comment: We are using XMLWorker class.

Comment: Hard to help without any of the code you tried. Web app - web forms or MVC; console / desktop app? How's the HTML being passed to XML Worker?